# How to get the score of filtered bi-grams in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, lda

Given a list of document words e.g. `[['cow','boy','hat','mat],['village','boy','water','cow']....]`, gensim can be used to get bi-grams as follows:

```
bigrams = gensim.models.Phrases(data_words, min_count=1,threshold=1) 
bigram_model = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigrams)
```

I was wondering as to how to get the score of each bi-gram detected in the bigram_model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is as simple as using:

```
bigram_model.phrasegrams
```

that yields something like below:

```
{(b'cow', b'boy'): 23.3228613654742079,
 (b'village', b'water'): 1.3228613654742079}
```

Answer (score 0):

score =

1. RJA

sentence_bleu(reference, candidate, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
print(score)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).